# XML parsing error Unexpected token position:TEXT @1:2?

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

**The Error which is showing is**

*Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@41d569a8)*

**I am following this tutorial** [AndroidHive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

but when I am using another url like

(http://example.com/ss.svc/APIabc?A=10&Key=XXXXX&From=19&To=221&Date=19-Apr-2016) to parse the data its **showing me error like-**

```
  04-19 15:39:17.349: E/Error:(29642): Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@41d501a8) 
04-19 15:39:17.349: D/AndroidRuntime(29642): Shutting down VM
04-19 15:39:17.349: W/dalvikvm(29642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41322438)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.androidhive/com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at com.example.androidhive.CustomizedListView.onCreate(CustomizedListView.java:48)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5203)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-19 15:39:17.379: E/AndroidRuntime(29642):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
```

**MY XML format is like this**

```
 <APIabc xmlns="http://exapmle.org/">
    <APIabcd xmlns:a="http://ac.ssc.org/2014/21/abfaggkk" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Route>
    <Time>2016-04-13 06:11:00 AM</Time>
    <Avail>xyz</Avail>
<thumb_url>http://api.androidhive.info/music/images/adele.png</thumb_url>
    <BusLabel/>
    </Route>
    </APIabc>
    </APIabcd>
```

Comment: post your CustomizedListView.java class

Comment: which line is the 48th?

Comment: yaa i posted see my edited question

Comment: Ye, but i need to know which line exactly is the 48th.. my guess is this one? map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));

Comment: NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG); this is 48th line

Comment: You problem is with your URL.. I tried to open it and i can't. Plus it is not in xml format. If you see the example at Android hive the link they give is a .xml and if you open it you can see the text in xml format, which does not happen with the link you are giving as URL

Comment: ok for some security reasons i havent published the original link i gave the dummy link ...but  i posted the XML Format whicn i am getting from that link see my heading "MY XML format is like this"

Comment: @RicardoBarroca i think you must have understood what i am trying to say.....i think its something  to do with UTF-8

Comment: @ricardo barroca did you get any help for me friend?

Comment: I seriously have no ideia if you have a valid XML

Comment: @RicardoBarroca see to it please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787216/getting-value-and-its-particular-key-on-spinner-click