# Getting value and its particular key on spinner click

Tags: java, android, android-intent, xml-parsing, android-toast

**I am getting the data in both the spinner1 and spinner 2 when spinner1 is selected then its corresponding data is automatically populated in spinner2**

Below is the XML format data getting from URL then-

```
<a:Pair>
<a:FromID>01</a:FromID>      <---This should Toast---->
<a:FromName>INDIA</a:FromName><---On selecting this from spinner------->
<a:ToID>40</a:ToID>
<a:ToName>TURKEY</a:ToName>
</a:Pair>

<a:Pair>
<a:FromID>10</a:FromID>
<a:FromName>USA</a:FromName>
<a:ToID>01</a:ToID>
<a:ToName>INDIA</a:ToName>
</a:Pair>

<a:Pair>
<a:FromID>19</a:FromID>
<a:FromName>CHINA</a:FromName>
<a:ToID>10</a:ToID>
<a:ToName>USA</a:ToName>
</a:Pair>

<a:Pair>
<a:FromID>40</a:FromID>
<a:FromName>TURKEY</a:FromName>
<a:ToID>01</a:ToID>
<a:ToName>INDIA</a:ToName>
</a:Pair>

</Result>
</Response>
```

But the thing is if **spinner1 data is USA selected** then I want to toast its **corresponding id i.e 10**  ...which i will use in future to pass to next activity also

[image: What i want]

**My below code works fine I just want when spinner1 is selected its id from XML data is selected and if spinner2 then also its corresponding id should toast.**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> title2;
    Button button;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner2;
    private EditText fromDateEtxt;
    //private EditText toDateEtxt;

    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    //private DatePickerDialog toDatePickerDialog;

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;

    ArrayAdapter<String> from_adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> from_adapter2;
    Map<String, List<String>> values = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        title2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        //spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                parse();

                from_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title);
                from_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                title2.clear();
                from_adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title2);
                from_adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


                spinner.setAdapter(from_adapter);
                //from_adapter2.clear();
                //from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinner2.setAdapter(from_adapter2);


            }

            private Object from_adapter(int i) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        });


    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        String lang_Name = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        List<String> lang_Key = values.get(lang_Name);
        from_adapter2.clear();
            for(String s : lang_Key){
                  from_adapter2.insert(s, from_adapter2.getCount());
            }
            from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ""+lang_Key,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

    protected void parse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "www.example.com");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:Pair");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                // get the a:W value
                String awValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:FromName").item(0).getTextContent();
                // add the above value in our map  as key if it isn't present in the map, this key will 
                // have a list associated with it in which ALL the values for a:R will be stored, if 
                // the awValue key is present then you just add the new a:R value to its list 
                if (!values.containsKey(awValue)) {
                    values.put(awValue, new ArrayList<String>());

                }
                // also add the value pointed by a:R to the list associated with a:W
                String arValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:ToName").item(0).getTextContent();
                values.get(awValue).add(arValue);

               // Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + arValue);
            }
             Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " +  values);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:FromName");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:ToName");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                title.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:Pair");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList2.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:ToName");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         
                title2.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title);
            title = new ArrayList<String>(set);
            // Collection<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(months);
            Set<String> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title2);
            title2 = new ArrayList<String>(set2);
            System.out.println("list are");
            System.out.println(set);
            System.out.println("list 2 are");
            System.out.println(set2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == fromDateEtxt) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        } else  {
            Log.d("errorrrr", "soryy");
        }

    }
}
```

**I am not able to pass the id to the corresponding data which are populated in the spinner and toast that id**

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate action on each spinner like this

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                     // Show your toast for Spinner 1
                    from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();// Changed
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                     // Show your toast for Spinner 2
               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I am able to get the spinner value on click but not able to get its correspinding <a:FromID>01</a:FromID>

Comment: @AndroidPutra Please see my changed line. from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged(); You need to refresh again second spinner when you selected first Value. Hope you got my point.

Comment: I think i am not able to explain you clearly....actually when I click on India its has corresponding id 10 which (is coming from the on-line xml data) I want that when India is selected 10 should toast

Comment: are you able to get id in first spinner  ?

Comment: Could you describe in detail where did you stored you xml ?

Comment: my xml is on-line due to security reasons as it contains key I have only posted the way of format it is coming from server....both the spinners are getting populated correctly the only thing i am not able to pass the ID to corresponding data and toast it when data from spinner is selected

Comment: Boss you need to store entire xml in a variable otherwise you need to manage a custom adapter.

Comment: ok...i am successfully able to pass the <a:FromName>INDIA</a:FromName> data to spinner but not able to append  the <a:FromID>01</a:FromID>  data to that data